# New to ising model, can't find answer to simple energy calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, simulations, ising-model

I'm trying to see why we get this energy config here [image: Ising Energy change]

As far as I understood, up/down or down/up contributes +, and same direction, ie up up or down down negative. So it should be all negative on the first picture. However there is a "random" plus to the right hand side. Can someone tell me why that is?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there's an error!

For any two adjacent sites $i, j \in \Lambda$ there is an interaction $J_{ij}$. The energy of a configuration is given by the Hamiltonian function

$$H(\sigma )=-\sum_{\langle i~j\rangle}J_{ij}\sigma _{i}\sigma _{j}-\mu \sum _{j}h_{j}\sigma_{j}$$
where the first sum is over pairs of adjacent spins (every pair is counted once).

In the most simple case ($J\equiv 0, \mu=0$ and $\sigma_i =\pm 1$), the Energy function can be reduced to 
$$H(\sigma )=-\sum_{\langle i~j\rangle}\sigma _{i}\sigma _{j}$$
then you are absolutely true, there is a mistake.

Comment: That's what I found out :) It was very confusing. Thanks for your answer :-)